# jQuery bind() problem?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have made a generic function to show jQuery dialogs in my app. this function simply

- Set the dialog title
- make an ajax call to a server side function and populate the dialog with the html returned
- open the dialog

Here is the function:

```
function loadDialog(action, id, title, onCloseHandler) {
    $("#__gsl_DialogPanel").dialog("option", "title", title);
    var url = action;
    if (id != "") url = url + "/" + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        url: url,
        data: {},
        success: function(response) {
            $("#__gsl_DialogPanel").html('').html(response).dialog('open');
        }
    });
    $("#__gsl_DialogPanel").bind("dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
        if (onCloseHandler != null)
            onCloseHandler();
    });
}
```

As you can see the function actually does even bind a function to the `dialogclose` event so when the dialog is closed that function get called. This feature is particularly useful if I use a dialog to add/edit/delete elements in a grid: I can pass a function that does a grid update and when the dialog is closed the grid will update itself.

I am experiencing that, in some cases, the function binded to the `dialogclose` event is called more than once and I am suspecting that the problem is related to the fact that multiple calls to my `loadDialog` function will bind multiple reference of the same close handler.

Am I correct? Do I have to explicitly unbind everything whn the dialog close?

thanks for helping!

**Update**:

As per the answers received I have simply unbinded and binded again the function handler and everything works! this is the updated code

```
$("#__gsl_DialogPanel").unbind("dialogclose").bind("dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
    if (onCloseHandler != null)
        onCloseHandler();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a nice syntax for custom events: `'eventName.pluginName'`
This way you can bind the same event, but differentiate between the different handlers.

calling `trigger('eventName')` will trigger all handlers

In your case you can unbind just your event, and leave others alone.

Example:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Button">
```

Javascript:

```
$('#btn'​).​bind('myEvent',function(){
    alert('myEvent.other plugins');
});

$('#btn').bind('myEvent.myPlugin',function(){
    alert('myEvent.myPlugin');
});

//use this in your loadDialog function for the dialogClose event
$('#btn').unbind('myEvent.myPlugin').bind('myEvent.myPlugin',function(){
    alert('myEvent.myPlugin');
});

$('#btn').trigger('myEvent');
​
```

You can try this [live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/bdsvK/).

Answer (score 1):

In DOM level 2, multiple listeners can be bound to an event on a given element, so it's perfectly possible for multiple calls to `loadDialog()` to bind multiple listeners to the `dialogClose` event.

If the element with the ID of `__gsl_DialogPanel` remains present in the DOM regardless of whether the dialog is displayed, you will definitely end up binding multiple listeners to the `dialogClose` event with multiple calls to `loadDialog()`.